# How to enter the Radio security code

Tags: honda, civic, audio

I have the radio security code now I need to know how to enter it. Can you help me please? I have a 2002 Honda Civic

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Do you have the eight digit serial number from the radio or do you have the actual five digit radio code?

Answer (score 1):

You can enter it using the preset buttons. You should see buttons that have numeric characters 1 through 6 or 1 through 7. Just use those to enter the code :)

Answer (score 0):

You press the buttons 1 and 6 at the same time while trying to turn on the radio again.